# Oracle Apex, apex_util.get_print_document not working over https

Tags: oracle-apex

I am working on a project where I generate and store pdf in the database using apex_util.get_print_document.

### It looks like this,

```
begin
l_report := apex_util.get_print_document (
p_application_id      => :APP_ID,
p_report_query_name   => 'query_name',
p_report_layout_name  => 'layout_name',
p_report_layout_type  => 'xsl-fo',
p_document_format     => 'pdf'  );

Update table_blob
Set report = l_report,
mimetype = 'application/pdf',
filename = :P1_INVOICE_NO||'.pdf',
report_saved_by = :USER,
report_saved_on = sysdate
Where Job_id = :P1_JOB;

End;
```

---

This works perfectly in http connection. So when I access the same page over https I am getting the below error. Please help!

ORA-20001: The printing engine could not be reached because either the URL specified is incorrect or a proxy URL needs to be specified.

Answer (score 1):

For APEX to be able to make outbound HTTP calls over SSL, a database wallet must be created and the configuration of it must be specified in APEX Instance Administration:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39151/adm_wrkspc002.htm#sthref384